# Animación JS diferentes en un foreach

Tags: php, javascript, html

tengo un foreach donde saca una especie de CARDS con la ficha de un centro, este ficha lleva la `ID="port"`para poder localizarla por JavaSCript. El problema está en que se llaman con la misma id y si me pongo encima de la primera se mueven las demás, pero si me pongo en la segunda, o tercera por ejemplo, no hace nada.

Supongo que hay que crear una especie de ciclo, pero automático, ya que se van a crear muchos registros y no puedo modificar el JS cada vez que se añada un registro nuevo.

QUERY

```
<?php
 $results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM centros WHERE estado = 1");
   foreach ($results as $centros){
?>

 <div id="port" class="portfolio valencia center" data-cat="valencia">
    <?php if ($centros['logo']== null) {
       echo "<img src=\"images/centros/cut.svg\" class=\"imgCentro1\">";
       }else {
       echo "<img src=\"images/centros/$logo\"  class=\"imgCentro1\">";
       } ?>
 </div>

<?php } ?>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
  $( "#port" ).mouseenter(function() {
    $('.imgCentro1').css("transform"," rotate(-45deg)");
    $('.imgCentro1').css("transition","1s");
  });
  $( "#port" ).mouseleave(function() {
    $('.imgCentro1').css("transform"," rotate(0deg)");
    $('.imgCentro1').css("transition","1s");
  });
```

Comment: ¿Podemos ver el **HTML** donde se muestre las imágenes que pretendes animar?

Comment: hola @phpMyGuel e añadido el HTML de la imagen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que el `ID` se trata de un identificador único que jamás debería de repetirse dentro de la misma página. Si rompes ese concepto el navegador no se va a comportar de la manera esperada.

Lo que yo haría sería seleccionar a los elementos por **clase** en vez de por **id** a la hora de enlazarles los eventos `mouseenter()` y `mouseleave()` y luego utilizar el identificador `this` para hacer referencia al elemento en el que se esté ejecutando el evento.

**HTML**

```
//Se le quitó la id para añadirle la clase "port"    
<div class="portfolio valencia center port" data-cat="valencia">
    <div class="cabeceraCentro"></div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$( ".port" ).mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find('.imgCentro1').css("transform"," rotate(-45deg)");
    $(this).find('.imgCentro1').css("transition","1s");
});

$( ".port" ).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find('.imgCentro1').css("transform"," rotate(0deg)");
    $(this).find('.imgCentro1').css("transition","1s");
});
```

Comment: Wow! es verdad con el `this` muchas gracias. Una pregunta y hay un forma de a la vez que entro en ese `this` poder hacer algo en los otros cards? como por ejemplo aplicarles una opacidad? gracias @phpMyGuel

Comment: Claro. ¿Sería hacer algo en todos los otros elementos con la clase **port** o en todos menos en el que se ejecuta la animación?

Comment: En todos menos en el que se ejecuta la animación, por ejemplo en este `.port` cuando paso el mouse por encima se gira la imagen de `.imgCentro1`.  Eso tiene que seguir pasando pero que por ejemplo las otras cards se vuelvan más opacitadas

Comment: Podrías usar la función **not()** de Jquery, quedando algo como: **$('.imgCentro1').not($(this).find('.imgCentro1')).css('opacity', '0.5');**

Comment: funciona correcto, pero esta función del resto tiene que actuar sobre la clase `.port` si cambio las propiedades que  me pasas, y lo cambio por port, se me opacitan todas

Comment: Si la opacidad se la quieres dar al elemento con la clase **port** sería entonces así: **$('.port').not($(this)).css('opacity', '0.5');** Date cuenta que el **this** es una referencia al elemento que tiene enlazado el evento que se ejecuta.

Comment: Estupendo!! funciona a la perfección. Muchas gracias @phpMyGuel